# Updated using yarn upgrade command but getting warnings to update more

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, package-managers

I ran `yarn upgrade --latest` and I got the below. But I thought I just upgraded why the below is asking me to update again? If so, should I and how to?

```
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > eth-json-rpc-middleware > eth-sig-util@1.4.2: Deprecated in favor of '@metamask/eth-sig-util'
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-block@1.7.1: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-tx@1.3.7: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-block > ethereumjs-tx@1.3.7: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-vm@2.6.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/vm. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-vm > ethereumjs-block@2.2.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-vm > ethereumjs-block > ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > eth-block-tracker > safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > eth-json-rpc-middleware > safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > eth-json-rpc-infura > json-rpc-engine > safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-vm > ethereumjs-common@1.5.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-vm > ethereumjs-block > ethereumjs-common@1.5.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > ethereumjs-vm > ethereumjs-block > ethereumjs-tx > ethereumjs-common@1.5.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > @walletconnect/qrcode-modal > @walletconnect/mobile-registry@1.4.0: Deprecated in favor of dynamic registry available from: https://github.com/walletconnect/walletconnect-registry
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning @walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning moralis > web3 > web3-eth > web3-eth-accounts > uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because the latest
version of `@walletconnect/web3-provider` package depends on packages of deprecated version.
So even though you upgrade the packages listed in package.json, the package's dependencies are not upgraded, causing the warning.
However, upgrading all of them is not recommended because dependency version mismatch can cause issues with the dependent package. The best way is to create PR at the dependency repo to upgrade deps.

Comment: Sorry, what is PR and how to create PR at the dependency repo to upgrade deps? It's my 2nd day using yarn.

Comment: PR is Pull Request. It is that you modify some code and request the repo owner to accept it. You can also create an issue. An issue is that you just tell about some changes without you modify the code. You can create issue by going the the package's github repo and request to upgrade deps.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that